# jqGrid dynamic columns based on other column in same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am busy with jqGrid and have the following question:

I have a column called status with dataField: Status. I want to use this field more than once, but jqxGrid doesn't allow me to use that dataField multiple times. SO I've used the following code to achieve, but yet it does not work:

```
<div data-bind="jqxGrid: {source: $data, autoheight: true,
            theme: 'classic',
            editable: true,
            selectionmode: 'singlecell',
            columns: [
                { text: 'Datum', dataField: 'Datum', width: 200, cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer2 },
                { text: 'Bonnummer', dataField: 'Bonnummer', width: 200, cellsalign: 'right' },
                { text: 'Code', dataField: 'GPCode', width: 200, cellsformat: 'c2', cellsalign: 'right' },
                { text: 'Omschrijving', dataField: 'Omschrijving', width: 200 },
                { text: 'ColloneVeld', dataField: 'ColloneVeld', width: 100 },
                { text: 'Status', index:'Status', dataField: 'BlokkadeBesluitValue', width: 100 },
                { text: 'Con', width: 100,formatter:'checkbox',formatoptions:{disabled:false}, cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer }
            ]}" id="jqxgrid">

    </div>
```

and the cellsrender code:

```
var cellsrenderer = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {

            var cellValue = jQuery("#jqxgrid").jqGrid('getCell', row, 'Status');
            alert(cellValue);
            return 'test'
        }
```

I get the error that jqGrid is not a function, and when a try to pass

```
var cellValue = jQuery("#jgxGrid").getCell( row, 'Status');
```

I got the message that getCell is not a function.

Everybody is talking that the reference didn't apply to the JS files, but when I use the function:

```
$("#source").html(JSON.stringify(data));
```

This works perfectly. So why doesn't work getCell or jqGrid?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `jQuery` or `$` is a problem

Comment: Do you really use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) or you use [jqxGrid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/category/jqxgrid/)?